# iexpress command line example to create EXE packages

Tags: iexpress

I need help with Example for Use iexpress command line to create EXE package.
I have a folder With multiple files and folders inside, and I want to create a single EXE file from this folder. Is it possible to help me with an example of how to create a command line for such a thing.

Answer (score 20):

IExpress.exe uses SED files, which are really just text files that describe the parameters used when building the package. To build a self-extracting installer on the command line, you just run IEXPRESS with the SED file as an argument:

```
iexpress /N Your_SED_Script.sed
```

The `/N` is to invoke unattended package building. Without it, the IExpress GUI wizard will simply pop up.

You can generate SED files by going through the IExpress wizard, or you can try to generate them automatically with some of your own code.

Let's look at the structure of an SED script to get you started.

Below is an example of an SED file I generated by going through the IExpress.exe GUI wizard once.
Most of these options aren't critical, but in the lower half you'll see **TargetName**, which specifies the filename of the resulting self-extracting package. FILE0, FILE1, FILE2 specify files in the package. **[SourceFiles]** begins the section that describes where IExpress should look for the files.

#### Source File Part

```
FILE0="TestProgram.exe"
FILE1="TestData.dat"
FILE2="TestLibrary.lib"
[SourceFiles]
SourceFiles0=C:\Users\user\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\TestProject\Debug\
SourceFiles1=C:\Users\user\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\TestProject\Debug\lib\
[SourceFiles0]
%FILE0%=
%FILE1%=
[SourceFiles1]
%FILE2%=
```

Here we have two different locations, defined as **SourceFiles0** and **SourceFiles1**. They each get their own sub-section, **[SourceFiles0]** and **[SourceFiles1]**, below which are references to each of the files in those locations.

```
[Strings]
. 
. 
. 
AppLaunched=TestProgram.exe
```

The **AppLaunched** parameter in the **[Strings]** section sets the file to run after extraction. Below it just contains the executable **TestProgram.exe**, but you can set batch files (*.bat) to run after extraction. If **Applaunched** is empty, the package will just extract the files.

There are a few resources available online, but I'll admit it was pretty hard to find any information about how to build self-extracting packages as opposed to just opening them. The Wikipedia entry is a good starting point.

[Wikipedia - IExpress](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IExpress)

[SED Overview](http://www.mdgx.com/INF_web/cdfinfo.htm)

#### Full SED Script

```
[Version]
Class=IEXPRESS
SEDVersion=3
[Options]
PackagePurpose=InstallApp
ShowInstallProgramWindow=0
HideExtractAnimation=1
UseLongFileName=1
InsideCompressed=0
CAB_FixedSize=0
CAB_ResvCodeSigning=0
RebootMode=I
InstallPrompt=%InstallPrompt%
DisplayLicense=%DisplayLicense%
FinishMessage=%FinishMessage%
TargetName=%TargetName%
FriendlyName=%FriendlyName%
AppLaunched=%AppLaunched%
PostInstallCmd=%PostInstallCmd%
AdminQuietInstCmd=%AdminQuietInstCmd%
UserQuietInstCmd=%UserQuietInstCmd%
SourceFiles=SourceFiles
[Strings]
InstallPrompt=
DisplayLicense=
FinishMessage=
TargetName=C:\Users\user\Documents\TestSED.exe
FriendlyName=All your SEDs are belong to us
AppLaunched=TestProgram.exe
PostInstallCmd=<None>
AdminQuietInstCmd=
UserQuietInstCmd=
FILE0="TestProgram.exe"
FILE1="TestData.dat"
FILE2="TestLibrary.lib"
[SourceFiles]
SourceFiles0=C:\Users\user\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\TestProject\Debug\
SourceFiles1=C:\Users\user\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\TestProject\Debug\lib\
[SourceFiles0]
%FILE0%=
%FILE1%=
[SourceFiles1]
%FILE2%=
```

Comment: Sorry to poke, but you can put _folders inside an executable with **iexpress**_?

Comment: I thought you couldn't!

Comment: To clarify, *yes*, you can put folders in the executable. But iexpress *will not* preserve folder structure when it unpacks, and you *must* select the files individually, which means manually recursing through every folder to add its files.

Answer (score 2):

Use the IExpress wizard to create a SED file once. In step "Packaged files" you can specify all files to be zipped.

Then use

```
iexpress.exe /N sed_file_name
```